# What colorspace is mix-blend-mode saturation from?

Tags: css, svg, mix-blend-mode

[The spec for blend-mode saturation](https://drafts.fxtf.org/compositing-1/#valdef-blend-mode-saturation) says:

> Creates a color with the saturation of the source color and the hue and luminosity of the backdrop color.

Originally I assumed it would be HSL as that's the only colorspace you can use in web development that has a saturation channel, but that's clearly not it:

```css
.color {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.expected-color {
  background: hsl(270, 25%, 50%);
}

.backdrop-color {
  background: hsl(270, 85%, 50%);
}

.source-color {
  mix-blend-mode: saturation;
  background: hsl(45, 25%, 50%);
}
```

```html
Expected
<div class="color expected-color"></div>

Actual
<div class="color backdrop-color">
  <div class="color source-color"></div>
</div>
```

It's not so easy to demonstrate HSV/HSB, but the testing I did using color converters (eg. [link](http://www.workwithcolor.com/color-converter-01.htm)) showed that it's not that color space either.

```css
.color {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.expected-color {
  /* HSB/HSV - 270, 25, 50 */
  background: #706080;
}

.backdrop-color {
  /* HSB/HSV - 270, 85, 50 */
  background: #491380;
}

.source-color {
  /* HSB/HSV - 45, 25, 50 */
  mix-blend-mode: saturation;
  background: #807860;
}
```

```html
Expected
<div class="color expected-color"></div>

Actual
<div class="color backdrop-color">
  <div class="color source-color"></div>
</div>
```

Likewise with LCH ([converter](http://colormine.org/convert/rgb-to-lch)) which doesn't have a saturation channel but it's chroma channel is practically an analog for saturation:

```css
.color {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.expected-color {
  /* LCH - 50, 25, 270 */
  background: rgb(90,121,161);
}

.backdrop-color {
  /* LCH - 50, 85, 270 */
  background: rgb(0,125,255);
}

.source-color {
  /* LCH - 50, 25, 45 */
  mix-blend-mode: saturation;
  background: rgb(157,107,90);
}
```

```html
Expected
<div class="color expected-color"></div>

Actual
<div class="color backdrop-color">
  <div class="color source-color"></div>
</div>
```

Seems to be consistent across Edge, Chrome, and Firefox.

So what colorspace is `mix-blend-mode: saturation` defined in? Or am I misunderstanding how it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a bit (a lot) more digging, and it looks like the math they're using is some weird combination of disparate colorspaces combined with general color theory:

The function for saturation described in the spec is:

```
B(Cb, Cs) = SetLum(SetSat(Cb, Sat(Cs)), Lum(Cb))
```

Where `Cb` is the backdrop color, and `Cs` is the Source color; both in sRGB space (just means `R`,`G`, and `B` are in the range `[0 - 1]`).

the functions used within this are defined as:

```
    ClipColor(C)
        L = Lum(C)
        n = min(Cred, Cgreen, Cblue)
        x = max(Cred, Cgreen, Cblue)
        if(n < 0)
            C = L + (((C - L) × L) / (L - n))

        if(x > 1)
            C = L + (((C - L) × (1 - L)) / (x - L))

        return C

    Lum(C) = 0.3 x Cred + 0.59 x Cgreen + 0.11 x Cblue

    SetLum(C, l)
        d = l - Lum(C)
        Cred = Cred + d
        Cgreen = Cgreen + d
        Cblue = Cblue + d
        return ClipColor(C)

    Sat(C) = max(Cred, Cgreen, Cblue) - min(Cred, Cgreen, Cblue)

    SetSat(C, s)
        if(Cmax > Cmin)
            Cmid = (((Cmid - Cmin) x s) / (Cmax - Cmin))
            Cmax = s
        else
            Cmid = Cmax = 0
        Cmin = 0
        return C;
```

We can ignoring `ClipColor` and the `SetX` functions, as we're really just interested in determining the colorspace(s) (if any). Which leaves:

```
Lum(C) = 0.3 x Cred + 0.59 x Cgreen + 0.11 x Cblue

Sat(C) = max(Cred, Cgreen, Cblue) - min(Cred, Cgreen, Cblue)
```

## What is `Lum`?

The name of the function and it's usage might have you assume that they're referring to the Luminance that is sometimes ascribed to the `L` in `HSL`, or the `B` or `V` in `HSB/HSV`. They're not. This function is used to determine the **relative brightness of a color to the human eye**. It comes from the [YIQ colorspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YIQ#From_RGB_to_YIQ):

[image: From RGB to YIQ]

Notice that the first row - which will map to the Y (Luma) value - is a perfect match (albeit, slightly more precise) with the magic numbers in the `Lum(C)` formula.

To contrast this:

the `B`/`V` channel in `HSB/HSV` is `Max(R,G,B)`.

the `L` channel in `HSL` is `( Max(R,G,B) - Min{R,G,B) ) / 2`.

## What is `Sat`?

This apparently IS actually Saturation (of a sorts), but it's not from any *particular* colorspace. It's more an abstraction of how you might think about saturation in the `RGB` colorspace. The first suggestion that this be a way to think about saturation seems to come from [this 2003 paper](http://www.cmm.mines-paristech.fr/%7Eserra/notes_internes_pdf/NI-230.pdf), which is largely a critique of the existing colorspaces of it's time, and a suggestion to use a since unused colorspace `IHLS`.

For contrast:

`S` in `HSB/HSV` is `( Max(R,G,B) - Min(R,G,B) ) / Max(R,G,B)` or `0` if `Max(R,G,B)` is `0`.

`S` in `HSL` is `( Max(R,G,B) - L ) / Min(L, 1 - L)` or `0` if `L` is `1` or `0`. (The same `L` as defined above).

---

The only conclusion I can draw from all this is that `mix-blend-mode: saturation` has nothing to do with colorspaces at all, and is more to do with "saturation" in a more general sense; and in much the same way `mix-blend-mode: luminosity` isn't necessarily about any particular colorspace so much it's as a way of retaining "the perception of brightness".

If we *were* to point a finger at the most likely candidate, it'd be the `YIQ` colorspace, which I hadn't heard of before delving into this. The oversimplification of *Saturation* used in the spec can be referred to as a measure of *Chrominance* which is what the `I` and `Q` channels collectively represent.

It seems that the naming of these blend-modes is unavoidably ambiguous to a software developer, as their intended audience is likely designers, not engineers.

Not the answer I wanted, but it does seem to be the answer.

### Update

I've just had an interesting exchange with one of the editors (authors?) of the spec. The justification for this mess is that (paraphrasing) "Adobe products have been doing it this way for the last 20 years and that's what people are used to". There's obviously no point interrogating that poor strain of reasoning too much, but I get the impression that the spec is largely a copy-paste of the existing blend modes implemented in photoshop and the like.

Comment: Huh, I'd have thought designers cared about this sort of thing, as someone who's had a hand in both. Anyway, I looked at your flag earlier today and was undecided on the comments, but now that you've answered your question I guess they can go.

Comment: Yeah, I believe it's meant to bridge the gap between designers familiar with Adobe products and developers writing CSS. I'm not surprised that this has just been the way it is for Adobe products (again, I'd have expected them to be more precise since that's what designers care about), but I'm glad FXTF made the conscious decision to follow them anyway for the sake of compatibility. Personally I do appreciate being able to use any of the existing blending modes from Photoshop right in my CSS and know it'll just work as it does in Photoshop (runaway browser bugs notwithstanding).